# Terrain Ground, lerp Grass and Snow in Cities: Skylines

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cities-skylines-api

I am working on a Seasons Mod for Cities: Skylines. My way is kind of good, and I found a way to change the ground texture to a snowy one by using

```
mat.SetTexture("_TerrainGrassDiffuse", grassTexture);
```

So that is working fine, but i dont want a hard cut between the seasons. So I came up with this idea: Lerping between the snow and the grass texture. Googled much, but I didn't come up with anything which works. So I want a lerp which fades in the snow texture and fades out the grass texture by a given amount of time, so I think a lerp is right here. I have no access to the shader, cause its a mod, and I would need decompiling for that..
I tried using

```
someMat.Lerp();
```

but I don't know which material I need to use for the someMat.
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

First off I like to note that `someMat.Lerp();` is **not** the solution for your problem. The `material Lerp()` function is used to change colors, while retaining the original shader and textures. As you wish to lerp the texture, this is not the case.

Further more I don't think there is a build in way to lerp textures in unity. But it seems you can use a shader to circumvent this issue. After a short googling trip I found this UnityScript solution [source](http://www.sundh.com/blog/2012/09/real-time-blend-2-textures-in-unity/), with a simple and nice sample of the a shader implemented solution

Shader and relevant code sample can also be seen below.

```
public void Update ()
{
     changeCount = changeCount - 0.05;

     textureObject.renderer.material.SetFloat( "_Blend", changeCount );
      if(changeCount <= 0) {
           triggerChange = false;
           changeCount = 1.0;
           textureObject.renderer.material.SetTexture ("_Texture2", newTexture);
           textureObject.renderer.material.SetFloat( "_Blend", 1);
      }

 }
}
```

and the sample shader as given in the blog:

```
Shader "TextureChange" {
Properties {
_Blend ("Blend", Range (0, 1) ) = 0.5 
_Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
_MainTex ("Texture 1", 2D) = "white" {}
_Texture2 ("Texture 2", 2D) = ""
_BumpMap ("Normalmap", 2D) = "bump" {}
}

SubShader {
Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
LOD 300
Pass {
    SetTexture[_MainTex]
    SetTexture[_Texture2] { 
        ConstantColor (0,0,0, [_Blend]) 
        Combine texture Lerp(constant) previous
    }       
  }

 CGPROGRAM
 #pragma surface surf Lambert

sampler2D _MainTex;
sampler2D _BumpMap;
fixed4 _Color;
sampler2D _Texture2;
float _Blend;

struct Input {
    float2 uv_MainTex;
    float2 uv_BumpMap;
    float2 uv_Texture2;

};

void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
    fixed4 t1 = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
    fixed4 t2 = tex2D (_Texture2, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;

    o.Albedo = lerp(t1, t2, _Blend);
    o.Normal = UnpackNormal(tex2D(_BumpMap, IN.uv_BumpMap));
}
ENDCG  
}

FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer, but as I said, I have no access to the built-in shader, and creating my own would result worse quality on the ground. Maybe I just need to extract the shader out of the unity files, and built something related in like that. So I did that, but the shader has 30000 lines, and I have problems finding my self through that mess..

Comment: @iRedCraft You might want to check out the modding fora. Allot of the shaders are being identified to sometimes even the native unity shaders. This would simplify it allot.

Comment: ok I done that on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/CitiesSkylinesModding/comments/3tb32u/changing_ground_textures_new_terrain_shader/ thanks anyways :)